# design pattern for AI 'intelligent agents'

Tags: design-patterns, artificial-intelligence, agent, reactor

is there a recommended design pattern for designing an AI scenario consisting of multiple intelligent agents that do not necessarily have to interact with each other.

Thinking it is basically a schema that follows proper object construction and deconstruction?
Some multiplexing forking a new agent and subsequently deleting the agent once job is complete

any recommendations here?

thanks!

Comment: What challenges do you need to overcome?

Comment: Needing to parallelize the work done by each intelligent agent. Each agent will have a series of tasks, right now, each agent and it's tasks are being executed in sequential order, but I would like to implement a pattern to address 'intelligent agents that complete tasks in parallel (multi-threaded design, agent per thread)'

Comment: I'm reading a great paper that I thought would be worth sharing, http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx5/4430361/4430362/04430411.pdf?tp=&arnumber=4430411&isnumber=4430362.

Answer (score 5):

Traveling:
patterns such as Itinerary, Forwarding, and Ticket encapsulate mobility mgmt of an agent for one or more destinations.

Task:
patterns such as Master-Slave and Plan are concerned with the break-down of task and how these tasks are delegated to one or more agents

Interaction:
patterns such as Meeting, Locker, Messenger, Facilitator, and Organized Group are concerned with locating agents and facilitating their interactions.